# How do I write a query for rolling a subtraction from the grand total to create a decay curve

Tags: mysql

I would like to subtract each ordered row's value from the grand total of the data set. The grand total is 2,014,217 which is the sum of all the views in the data set. Here is the data set below and what I am looking for:

```
viewing           | views  | total  
------------------------------------
a0100             | 236303 | 1777914
a0100|a0101       |   9260 | 1768654
a0100|a0101|a0102 |  26670 | 1741984
```

The total is going to be the grand total minus 236,303 which is 1,777,914 then the next total is 1,777,914 minus 9,260 which is 1,768,654 and so on.

Can someone help?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to keep track of a previous row's value.

Try this solution:

```
SELECT     @vw:=CONCAT(@vw, '|', a.viewing) AS viewing
           a.views,
           CASE @total 
               WHEN 0 THEN @total:=b.viewsum - a.views
               ELSE        @total:=@total - a.views
           END AS total
FROM       tbl a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(views) AS viewsum FROM tbl) b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @vw:='') vw_init
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @total:=0) total_init
```